# Is close(channel) a blocking operation?

Tags: go

Is `close(channel)` a blocking operation? Does it wait until the buffered channel has finished consuming messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `close` function is not a blocking operation. The function records that no more values will be sent to the channel.

The application can receive buffered values after the call to `close`.

The specification [describes close in more detail](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Close).